# customized QR scanner and reader

Tags: javascript, android, qr-code

I want to know if there is a way to create a custom QR code that can only be read by a specific scanner designed specially for it. This means that all other QR scanners will not be able to read my custom code except mine.

I have googled for "custom QR code" and all I was able to get is how to put a logo on a QR code.

I will be greatful if anyone can provide me with a link, PDF, video or any relevant meterial(s) that can guide me towards archiving this task.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Since a QR code is produced based on a standard that is understood by all QR code readers, you won't easily be able to make a 'real' QR that's generally unreadable but still functional.

The two options are to rework the QR standard for your own purposes, creating your own reader software and your own code generating software, or to use some kind of encryption on the information to be included in a regular QR code that your intended users have some other way of solving.

Let's say the QR directs the user to a web page. The page could be password protected with a difficult-to-guess password, which is printed alongside the QR in plain text. The QR reader won't be able to read the password but the user will.

Comment: How about encrypting the data so that regular scanners will not be able to get the info (because it will appear like text only), then create a regular scanner that can further decrypt the data for use, would that be a possible option? Thanks for the reply BTW.

Comment: @wubsite sure you could. But that would entail building a single-use QR reader application that would only be good for the encrypted codes and nothing else. Surely the path of least resistance would be something like I describe - a password or some other action on behalf of your intended user that they would know about and the uninitiated would not. You could use existing infrastructure (existing QR readers, the web) and not need the overhead in time and effort to reinvent the wheel...